# How can I send data from ListView into TextField in Flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, list, dart, text

Since my problem is not with a code, I will explain it to the images.

[image]

There are 3 fields that I think are textFields (Müşteri, Marka, Ürün). Clicking on these fields;

[image]

This opens a list. When I tap an option from this list;

[image]

It writes my chosen option inside this textField.

- **Which Widgets and how do I need to use it so that I can do this?**
- **How can I print data from a list into textField or textFormField?**
- **How can I redirect to a list when textField is clicked?**

Answer (score 0):

So First You Need To Build Your From With The `TextFormField` feild and assign a `TextEditingController` to That Field,
Create Your `ListView` With Suggestions And Make it Pop With Result when an Item is Pressed,
Now Use The `TextFormField` `onTap` function To Navigate To The `ListView` And then Assign The Returned Value To The Field Using The Controller

Answer (score 0):

You can use `TextEditingController` to make that functions that you need.